# confusion related to implicit contructors and constructor chaining

Tags: java

As per constructor chaining base constructor should be called when a derived class object is created and assigned to base class reference. 
And there is no default constructor in base class but then there is an explicit parameterized constructor, so java compiler does not provide default constroctor.
Without the statement "this(10);" compiler complains but then as soon as its added, compiler is fine with it. WHY??
I mean why does it not try to call the base class default constructor after adding "this(10);". It should have done a super call and then executed the added statement.

```
class Parent{
    public Parent(int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(){
        this(10);//default value
    }
    public Child(int a) {
        super(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this(10);` invokes the other constructor which invokes the superclass constructor. If you don't write `this(10);` then there is no superclass constructor that can be invoked implicitly.

Comment: I mean why does it not try to call the base class default constructor after adding "this(10);". It should have done a super call and then executed the added statement.

Comment: It doesn't need to do an implicit `super()` call to initialise the parent class, because the other constructor (which is invoked) does an explicit `super()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification ([§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)) defines what happens when you create a new instance; I highlighted the most important parts for your question.

> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of **another constructor in the same class** (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, **continue with step 5**.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then **this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super)**. Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.

So, the key points are:

- Your first constructor explicitly invokes the second constructor, so step 2 above applies; the second constructor is executed, and then step 3 is **skipped**.
- Step 3 is where the superclass constructor gets called, so that means when a constructor invokes another constructor from the same class, then it does not *directly* invoke a superclass constructor.
- However, if you delete `this(10);` from the first constructor, then the first constructor does not invoke another constructor of the same class, so step 3 applies, and a superclass constructor is implicitly invoked. This causes an error because there is no superclass constructor that can be implicitly invoked (with no arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The default/implicit constructor is there only if there is no other constructor.

By adding

```
public Parent(int a) {
    System.out.println(a); 
}
```

you remove the default constructor of `Parent`.

If you want to keep the default constructor, you can write it yourself like this:

```
public Parent(){
}
```

The following constructor

```
public Child(){

}
```

will be automatically replaced to

```
public Child(){
    super();
}
```

This replacement will happen if there is no constructor call(`this()` or `super()`) in the first line.

This secures that a super constructor is called in any case.

The replacement will fail if there is no constructor without arguments in the super-class (if you have replaced the default constructor with a parameterized constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Because if you don't add `this()` to `Child()` constructor - compiler will insert `super()` statement and thus expect no-arg constructor in `Parent` class.

```
class Parent{
    public Parent(int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(){
        // this(10);// Commenting this(10) as if it did not exist.
        super() // inserted by compiler unless you put this() or super() yourself
    }
    public Child(int a) {
        super(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```